# Amazon Redshift size increase

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, size

I have inserted data from one table to another table, after inserting the data the size of the table is increased to 30mb more with the actual size and the stats_off is also increased to 100.Can any one give me a reason why the size of the table is increased and how to reduce the stats_off of the table?

Comment: How did you copy the table?  There are a number of ways this could happen depending on what method you used to duplicate the table.  What was the size of the original table?  Is 30mb growth a doubling of size or 10% growth?  The stats_off percentage is easily fixed with an ANALYZE <table> command.  Or if you haven't disabled auto_analyze, just wait for the system to perform the operation.

Comment: @Bill Weiner First of all Thank you
First i have created a table using DDL  commands (create table  table_name.......    command)
Then I have inserted data using insert commands(insert into table_name.....command)
The size of the original table is 836 mb
The size of the copied (new table) is 868 mb.

Answer (score 1):

So the table is growing by 5% when you copy the contents from one table to the other.  I'll assume that the compression (encodings) are the same between table as this can increase the table size.  You say that you insert data using "insert commandS" (plural) and this can affect the size.  The unit of storage in Redshift is the 1MB "block" - this is the smallest unit that can be saved.  The block is also the unit for coherency.  If I save 1 row of data each column's size will be 1MB.  There is always some empty space at the end of each column.

Now if you inserted half of your data, committed, and then inserted the other half there will be partial blocks for the first insert AND partial blocks for the second insert.  This will lead to some increase in table size on disk.  These partial blocks will be for every column and for every slice.  You could easily see an increase of 32MB just from this effect.

To reclaim the space lost to these gaps you need to run VACUUM on the table.  This will sort and compact the data in the table.

The above assumes that the DDL for the table didn't change.  There are a number of ways in which changing the DDL will affect the table size.  The compression modes are a clear example but even the distribution key and style can affect table size.  It all comes down to how the data is allocated into blocks and stored on disk.

As mentioned before ANALYZE will create the stats for the table.

Comment: I have inserted using a single insert statement only I did use multiple insert statements to insert data into it. May I know the exact reason for it or where can I find it?

Comment: AWS publishes "what to do" but not a lot on "why".  You can see their advice on adding to tables with COPY here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-single-copy-command.html but they don't say how the multiple COPYs create the need for VACUUM.  re:Invent talks cover this but finding the right one can take some time.  A few people have tried to compile their knowledge for others - https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.jefclaes.be/amazon-redshift-fundamentals/aws-redshift-fundamentals.html (see section 4.1) but these get stale as it is hard to keep up with changes.

Comment: I've worked with the Redshift team on many client engagements and taken their non-public training.  There is a ton of good information out there but it is just hard to find.  The good news is that once you understand the basic internals of Redshift the best practices fall out from this knowledge.  I give Redshift training courses for clients that want to know more about how this great system works.

Comment: So the reason this happens is because base unit of storage on Redshift is the 1MB block.  Specific pieces of data are contained within these blocks and clearly a lot of data can be stored in 1MB.  When you change 1 piece of data within a block you are creating a new version of the block.  If you are adding data new blocks are created to store this new information (modifying existing blocks to use empty space is too expensive).  So lots of INSERTs creates lots of partially filled blocks.  A single INSERT creates fewer partially filled blocks.

Comment: The reason that are never "changed" (blocks are immutable) is because of MVCC (coherency control).  Redshift is a multi-user data base and many versions of each table need to be available and consistent at every point in time to every user.  If I start changing a table the "old" version must still be available to others up until I COMMIT my changes and even then these other users will see the old version IF they began working with the table before I committed.  (Table data doesn't change in the middle of doing work.)  Multiple INSERTs means multiple table versions need to be supported.